# Line break using \n working in email but not in shopping cart

Tags: php, javascript, line-breaks

I'm using the code below to store checkbox items in a MySQL database.  The 3rd line down is where I need to put a line break between each item.  I tried `<br>` or `<br />` and even though it looks great on the screen in the standard page, it actually shows the `<br>` or `<br />` html in the email receipt and does NOT do a line break.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['swatchname']);$i++) {
  $swatchname.= $_POST['swatchname'][$i];
  $swatchname.="<br />";  
}
```

In my javascript to send the email I have been using \n to do line breaks in the emails and it works perfectly.

Question is.. what method or character would I use to see it correctly in both email and on standard html page?  I don't want to list the items with a comma between.  Client needs it listed.

Comment: html formatted email and <br> or you will need to accommodate 2 options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you changed the headers for the email so the email client understands it as a html document instead of a common text format?

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Adding content headers makes the email act like a html page but just a email so the client can view a stylised email

**Edit:** some email clients don't accept html as the content type but most of the major ones do

Comment: Very good point.  So is it better to go this route or the serialize method I found - listed below?  It seems to give me better control but I'm open to better solutions.  Since some emails don't accept html I may avoid it if I can for cleanliness.

Comment: yes but with this example of 'serialize' you're only putting the data in to MySQL database which will still pose the question of emailing the client the 'receipt' so you will still have the same problem with the line breaks and also if you want to make a store, you would like the email to be some images and styling instead of just plain text.

Comment: Perfect.  That makes a lot of sense.  May as well put this option in now so that later we won't be limited to how the receipt can look.  Excellent points!

Comment: Last question - MIME-Version wording shows up next to company email sent to website user.  It this going to be in there visually?  Not a huge deal but I figured that kind of code would be hidden.

Comment: ok u must of added it in wrong but here http://pastebin.com/9Kbxn3Qs is a example I use it for my website so yer u can change it for what you need to

Comment: here is a example i used when i was in ur situation http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Use \n in emails and when viewing on website use `nl2br` PHP function.

Comment: Also check second answer if you want use html. Remebmer though that not all email clients serve html well.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own answer, you should edit your answer. Click the edit link (to the right of the score) and modify your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint PhpMyCoder - still sleeping I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial about "serialize".

It's a way to store the checkbox selections in the database.  Follow the user-friendly tutorial. http://evolt.org/node/60222/

Then, where the tutorial shows to `print $variable.", ";`  I made it `print $variable."<br />";` so that it will give line breaks on the html page.  On the page where it sends the customer an email receipt I made it `print $variable."\n";` which seems to be working on email.

Note:  Make sure to follow the tutorial and unserialize or you'll end up with jumbled looking code and think something went wrong.  Also use the loop to pull each checkbox item out.